# This error occurs when I try to lock the cursor in the center of the screen

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my complete code, can someone help me.

```
public float rotationSpeed;
public Transform target, player;
float mouseX, mouseY;

void Start()
{
    Cursor.visible = false;
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode; ;
}

void LateUpdate()
{
    cameraControl();
}
```

> Assets\ThirPersonCamerController.cs(14,28): error CS0119: 'CursorLockMode' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Which CursorLockMode do you *want* to assign to `Cursor.lockState`? For example, `CursorLockMode.None`, `CursorLockMode.Locked` or `CursorLockMode.Confined` would probably compile...

Comment: `Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;` perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pick a lock mode:

```
Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
```

Your choices are `None`, `Locked`, and `Confined`, but `Locked` seems to best fit your needs.  See the Unity reference at   https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CursorLockMode.html